# Refering to structure in structure, in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, linked-list

In ANSI C, I'm trying to add an item to the end of a linked-list, using the following structures:

```
typedef struct items{
    char itemname[30];
    int damage;
    int defense;
}items;


typedef struct itemlist{
    struct items item;
    struct itemlist *next;
} itemlist;
```

In short, **itemlist** is a "cell" struct in the list, and **items** is what contains the data. I try to refer to them as this:

```
itemlist* additem(itemlist *itemslist, items data){
   itemlist *moving, *new;

   new = (itemlist*) malloc(sizeof(itemlist));

   /* These 3 lines are not working*/
   strcpy(new->item->itemname,data->itemname);
   new->item->damage = data->damage;
   new->item->defense = data->defense;

   new->next = NULL;

   if (itemslist == NULL)     /* empty list? */
      return new;

   for (moving = itemslist; moving->next != NULL; moving = moving->next); 

   moving->next = new;

   return itemlist;
}
```

My question is, how do I refer to these structure in structure types?
The error messages read as:

**error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct items')**

**error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'items')**

Thank you for your time

Comment: If it's not a pointer to a structure, you just use the `.` operator. Also, watch out for "new" as it is a reserved keyword in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item` in `itemlist` is not a pointer to an `item` but the actual `item` so you don't use `->` you use `.` as in.

```
new->item.damage
```

Same with the function argument `data`.

As an aside, it's generally a bad idea to use C++ keywords like `new` in C code.  If you ever want to compile this with a C++ compiler it's going to be a pain.  Or worse, if you wind up with C++ keywords in your headers then you can't even expose the header to a C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

The item data is passed by value to the function so you need to use the . operator instead of -> here.

Comment: What function? It's an assignment.

Comment: @JonahNelson I believe doynax is references the `data` parameter to the function and the `data->` operations.

Comment: Jonah: "data" is passed to additem by value rather than as a pointer, so it must be dereferenced through "." instead of "->" in the assignments.

Comment: Well, that's just the same problem, only it's on the rhs, isn't it? He's got the problem on both sides, and the real problem is that `->` is a dereferencing operator in addition to `.`, and nothing needs to be dereferenced.